# change color of icon in MDToolbar in kivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to change the MDToolbar left_action_item icon color. Its defaulting to white, but now i want to change it to red. Whats the simplest way to do this? I've tried almost everything (text_color, bg_color, etc) all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the color of the icons in the toolbar.

Comment: so if thats impossible, how do i put my own custom icon then?

Comment: That's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `specific_text_color: 1,0,1,1` you can change the color of the text inside the toolbar. It changes both the text AND the icon. I have no idea how to change only the icon. Maybe this helps.

At the moment iam having trouble changing the icon color of a `OneLineIconListItem`. I think its the same constraint we are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like these, I recommend searching the [KivyMD repository](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD) for the relevant widget class, and then poking around to see how it's being defined, what the relevant IDs are, and so forth. For instance, [this line](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/d4d60310895f43b3cb02c012af0426dfe275b3e0/kivymd/uix/toolbar.py#L507) in [toolbar.py](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/d4d60310895f43b3cb02c012af0426dfe275b3e0/kivymd/uix/toolbar.py) seems to define the icons in the toolbar:

```py
def update_action_bar(self, action_bar, action_bar_items):
    #...
    action_bar.add_widget(
        MDIconButton(
            icon=item[0],
            on_release=item[1],
            opposite_colors=True,
            text_color=self.specific_text_color,
            theme_text_color="Custom",
        )
    )
    #...
```

Here we learn that the toolbar's icons are of class `MDIconButton`, and they have a `text_color` color attribute which seems to be setting the color.

Looking at [where the function above is called](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/d4d60310895f43b3cb02c012af0426dfe275b3e0/kivymd/uix/toolbar.py#L496), we see that these icons are being added as widgets to `self.ids["left_actions"]` and `self.ids["right_actions"]` respectively:

```py
def on_left_action_items(self, instance, value):
    self.update_action_bar(self.ids["left_actions"], value)

def on_right_action_items(self, instance, value):
    self.update_action_bar(self.ids["right_actions"], value)
```

Knowing all that, now in our own code, say in the `build()` function of our `MainApp`, we can access and modify the attribute:

```py
def build(self):
    # ... 
        
    # get the root widget
    self.root = root = Builder.load_file('root.kv')

    # get toolbar
    toolbar=root.ids.toolbar
    
    # get the icons on the right
    action_items = toolbar.ids.right_actions.children

    # loop over the icons
    for item in action_items:
        # change the color
        item.text_color=(1,0,0,1) # red
```

This doesn't need to be in build(), it just needs to be somewhere you can access the toolbar widget by its ID somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Using both **md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color** and **text_color: rgba('#F0F0F0')** allowed me to change the color of icon buttons within MDToolbar.